# How to retrieve a user using its object Id in parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using parse.com as my database for my website.I want to retrieve a user information using its object Id in java script. I can retrieve other classes object but there nothing mention that how one can retrieve user using its id.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users): "Parse.User is a subclass of Parse.Object, and has all the same features, such as flexible schema, automatic persistence, and a key value interface. All the methods that are on Parse.Object also exist in Parse.User. The difference is that Parse.User has some special additions specific to user accounts."

This means you can retrieve a user data just like any Parse object (e.g., by creating a query or fetching an unfetched object). Here's an example:

```
var userObjectId = "XXXXXXXX" // replace objectId with an actual "xyz123" id
var someUser = Parse.User.createWithoutData(userObjectId);  
someUser.fetch()
  .then(function(fetchedUser){
    console.log(fetchedUser)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. You solved my problem. Thanks again.